Understanding 浮気とか以前にその行動はよくないかと
The below short dialogue is about whether going to 合コン is considered cheating or not:

A: ねえ、合コンは浮気だと思う?
B: う～ん…浮気とか以前にその行動はよくないかと

I have doubts on how to parse 浮気とか以前にその行動. It seems like とか has the same function as など and その行動 refers to 浮気 and all activities related to 浮気 like going to 合コン, is that right?

No. その行動 refers not to 浮気 but 合コン (and 合コン only).

B: う～ん…浮気とか以前にその行動はよくないかと
B: Hmm... Before we talk about whether it's cheating, I think such an activity (=going to 合コン) is not just right.


Thanks again. 浮気とか is modifying 以前に, right?

@weeab00 This ～以前 is used as a suffix (we usually say それ以前の問題 rather than それの以前の問題). This is basically outside the modifier-modifiee framework.
